# Google Sheets email notification when date in a column is tomorrow

Tags: css, excel, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I'm a little clueless when it comes to scripting, is there a block of code I can add to the script editor when a date in a single column (say column a) is tomorrow?

Just a once per day email in the morning would be fantastic.

I currently have conditional formatting set up to change the colour of the cell when the date is tomorrow but an email notification would be far more useful

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is [`GmailApp.sendEmail()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app#sendemailrecipient-subject-body).

However, this cannot be *run* in the Script Editor. It can only be triggered if the sheet cell value is modified through user input. This particular [Google Docs Help Forum post](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/5YFvf4UKAv8) discusses it.

Accepted answer from the link above:

> Replace existing code with:
>
> Note: This script cannot be run from the script editor. It can only be run by entering a number less than 3 in col M after the trigger is set up.
>
> ```
> function missingNotification(e) {
>   //Add the trigger from the Resources menu in the Dev Editor
>   //DevEditor>Resources>Current Project's Triggers>Add trigger
>   // missingNotification -- From spreadsheet -- On edit
>   var r = e.range;
>   var s = r.getSheet();
>   var ss = e.source;
>   var sName = s.getSheetName();
>   if(sName != "sheet" || r.getColumn() != 13) return;
>   var value = e.value;
>   if(value >= 3) return;
>   var value2 = s.getRange(r.getRow(), 10).getValue();
>   value = value.toString();
>   var email = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
>   GmailApp.sendEmail(email, 'My Notification', 'Missing ' + value2 + ', there is ' + value + '\n\n'+ss.getUrl());
> }
> ```
>
> Save the code and set up the On edit trigger from the Resources menu per comments in code
>
> Once this is done if it still doesn't email then Close the Spreadsheet and reopen and retry entering number in M